# How can we read the "View Page Source" Code in the Webbroswer?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a requirement to read the Table content in the page source code.For normal HTML tables and grid view after rendering convert into HTML also i need to find the content also.Please suggest me some good links.I need to find the content of the Table in the Text File using C# in Asp.Net.
Thanks in-advance :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please note our FAQ suggests ["the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Please also read [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more details on what we, as a community, like to see in questions. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure, you can do so easily with the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

[Parsing HTML Documents with the Html Agility Pack](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx)